# How to hide the subView based on textfield value in iOS?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, subview

I am having four SubViews and two `TextFields` `stateText` and `providertext`.

If I click the `stateText` it shows a `UIPickerView` with two values. If I select the first value in the `UIPickerView` the view should not change and if I select the second value, this means that only third SubView has to change. In the same time, the selected picker value populates to `TextFields`.

If I select second value means the third SubView changes. But TextField values are not populated. Only this newSubView becomes active. Here is my Code:

PickerView Done Action

```
if([stateText.text isEqual:@"SecondValue"])
{
    [self newSubView];
}

-(void)newSubView
{
    UIView *loginView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+160, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
    loginView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
}
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are adding a new subview every time the second value is chosen instead of adding it once (or showing us where you remove it), what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Just am changing the `ThirdsubView` to `NewSubView` if i click the second value. But the Values in the First and second Subview are Disabled.I need values in the first and second view after the `NewSubView` appears.

Comment: You need to store references to the views at the local properties to be able to access them later.